# How to replace element in data.table by condition (without loop)?

Tags: r, data.table

I have 3 `data.table` with weekdays in first column and numeric in the rest of the column. 
  In first `DT(DT1)`, it has 7 rows and `n` columns (`n>2`) of numeric data on each column. And the rest `DT (DT2, DT3)` have 7 rows and 2 columns with one numeric column.

I would like to replace element in each column (except the Weekdays column) which less than or equal to the element in `DT2`  by element in `DT3` with the same weekdays.

```
x = c(8.38877450980392, 7.94021071115013, 7.95032679738562, 7.44576124567474, 
8.83645276292335)
y = c(83.8877450980392, 79.4021071115013, 79.5032679738562, 74.4576124567474, 
88.3645276292335)
DT1 = data.table(WeekDay = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), a = abs(rnorm(7)*100), b = abs(rnorm(7)*100), c = abs(rnorm(7)*100), d = abs(rnorm(7)*100))
DT2 = data.table(WeekDay = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), criteria = x)
DT3 = data.table(WeekDay = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), Replace_Value = y)
```

Is there a way to done it without loop?
Using only base R please?
Thank you.

Comment: A. Your example is not reproducible; x, y have 5 elements, your week has 7. B. why not merge the data.tables

Comment: It's my shameful mistake. I intend to create x,y with 7 elements. Thanks^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
setkey(DT1, WeekDay)
setkey(DT2, WeekDay)
mx.data <- as.matrix(DT1[, letters[1:4], with=F])
(DT1[DT2][DT3][, letters[1:4]:=as.data.table(ifelse(mx.data < criteria, Replace_Value, mx.data))])
```

First I merge all the tables as Shadow suggested.  Then, using a matrix I created with the data in `DT1` I use `ifelse` against `criteria`, which should recycle `criteria` for each column.  Then I assign the result of the `ifelse` by first transforming it into a `data.table` to columns `a-d` with the `:=` replacement operator.

As shadow noted, I had to change your criteria so they have the right number of days.  Also, I had to make your criteria a bit larger as they were never met (values in `DT1` always greater than `crtieria`).  Here is what I did to your data:

```
x = c(8.38877450980392, 7.94021071115013, 7.95032679738562, 7.44576124567474, 
      8.83645276292335, 50, 25)
y = c(83.8877450980392, 79.4021071115013, 79.5032679738562, 74.4576124567474, 
      88.3645276292335, 50, 25)
set.seed(1)
DT1 = data.table(WeekDay = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), a = abs(rnorm(7)*100), b = abs(rnorm(7)*100), c = abs(rnorm(7)*100), d = abs(rnorm(7)*100))
DT2 = data.table(WeekDay = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), criteria = x * 7)
DT3 = data.table(WeekDay = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), Replace_Value = y)
```

Comment: Oh! this is a new technique for me. It's work very well. Thank you.

Comment: @user3305468, to the extent this answers your question, please consider marking it as answered.  Thanks.